What is the elegant way to overload ros2 API?
Currently I have the following need: I want to implement two APIs for my navigation node: one is to accept a pose and navigate to pose, the other to to accept a pose and navigate to a pose near it. If I  implement them in action server, I need to create two actions and two action servers, which makes it a little bit redundant. What is the elegant way to overload a ros2 API like this?
I suggest some functions in a node can be overloaded to implement this, but I'm not sure whether it is the proper method. Welcome for discussion!
